# Image not rendering on website using Flask

Tags: python, flask, web

I am a newbie to Flask.I am creating my first project on Flask titled Image Processing using OpenCV.The home page consists of clickable cards which on clicking will direct users to the suitable pages.In the home page I want to insert a welcome gif but it seems that Flask is not able to render image on the browser despite providing the right link in the src attribute of img's tag.The relevant img tag

```
<img src="/static/images/welcome.gif" />
```

The project structure  [image]

Routes.py code

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/options',methods=['GET','POST'])
def options():
    return render_template('options.html')
```

Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/welcome.gif` ? (Assuming your app is running on your local host)

Comment: @DanSafee Upon entering http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/welcome.gif I am getting a Not Found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, from the project structure screenshot, that your `static` directory is a sibling to `app`, not a child directory. `static` should be a child directory of `app`.